# Beautiflsoup Create Soup With A Snippet of Page Source

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Normally whenever I'm using Beautifulsoup to extract data a simple

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html5lib")
```

Easy. Job done.

But I'm dealing with a site which has a *lot* of data on it. It's already loaded so I don't need to worry about loading times but I think the real killer is having my find_all's go through page source I don't need to be looking at.

I know I can narrow down the data I'm looking for once I've made the soup by navigating to the class etc.. and that is working but it is pretty slow. In fact even creating the soup with the page_source is pretty slow.

I've tried variations on

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.find_element_by_class_name('box'), "html5lib")

But without success. Is it possible to do something like this without fist looking through all of the source code? I guess in some form it would still have to load the source to just find the class I want it to look at. But a smaller soup might be faster to navigate through after it is downloaded.

I'd appreciate anyone who can point me in the right direction here.

TL;DR my soup from page_source is huge takes time to naviate through with selenium can I limit my soup to a certain classname or something before navigating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, this is exactly what [`SoupStrainer`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-only-part-of-a-document) is about:

> The `SoupStrainer` class allows you to choose which parts of an incoming document are parsed.

For example, if you want `BeautifulSoup` to parse only elements having `box` class:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

only_box = SoupStrainer(class_="box")
BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html5lib", parse_only=only_box)
```

As a side note, if speed really matters, consider switching from `html5lib` to `lxml.html` parser:

```
BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml", parse_only=only_box)
```

Comment: Ah perfect! You've no idea how much better you made my life this evening. And I'll give lxml a go but it tends to miss things html5lib seems to pick up.